# Powershell Path Replacement

Tags: string, powershell, text, replace

Hey it's me again with my paths :D

I write my Paths into a TXT-File.

Ex:

```
C:\Ex\am\ple\path.txt  
C:\Ex\am\ple\file.txt  
C:\Ex\am\ple\text.txt
```

Now I want to replace the "*.txt" at the end of every Path.

I tried the following:

```
(Get-Content ".\MYPATHS.txt") | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "\*.txt"}| Set-Content ".\MYPATHS.txt"
```

Where's is my fault?

Comment: Try `$_ -replace "\.txt"`

Comment: That replaces nothing.

Comment: or just [string]'C:\Ex\am\ple\file.txt'.TrimEnd('txt') + 'new' ...btw, doesnt '-replace' require 2 operands?

Comment: or if you insist on regex -- 'C:\Ex\am\ple\file.txt' -replace '.txt', '.new' -- yould better anchor the regex at the end though

Comment: @JaquelineVanek Sorry I'm quite new at powershell and my english-skills are not that good. May you explain a bit mor precise?

Comment: replace with what? or do you mean to remove the `.txt` ?

Comment: @Avshalom I want to remove the "path.txt" and "file.txt". With replace, I mean replace with an empty string (to remove it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

k, if you need just the path(without the files):

```
'C:\Ex\am\ple\path.txt', 'C:\Ex\am\ple\file.txt' | Split-Path -Parent
```

the list above

> 'C:\Ex\am\ple\path.txt', 'C:\Ex\am\ple\file.txt'

replaces 'Get-Content'. Output:

```
C:\Ex\am\ple
C:\Ex\am\ple
```

Comment: great example of not well explained question, @Jaqueline vote up for understanding